# Create when parent checked child too checked?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have problem parent child checkbox when I checked parent child not checked

Here is my code

```
<ul id="treeview">
                            @foreach ($parent_menus as $parent_menu)
                                <li>
                                    {{ $parent_menu->Description }}
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="pc-box" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}">
                                    <ul class="example">
                                        @foreach ($child_menus1 as $child_menu1)
                                            @if ($parent_menu->ModuleID == $child_menu1->HeaderId)
                                                <li data-expanded="true">
                                                    {{ $child_menu1->Description }}
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="cc-box" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        @foreach ($child_menus2 as $child_menu2)
                                                            @if ($child_menu1->ModuleID == $child_menu2->HeaderId)
                                                                <li>
                                                                    {{ $child_menu2->Description }}
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="cc-box" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu2->ModuleID }}">
                                                                </li>
                                                            @endif
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
```

Here is my Script jquery

```
 $(".cc-box").click(function () {
        if (!this.checked)
            $(this).closest("ul").prev().fadeIn().find(".pc-box").prop("checked", false);
    });
```

When I checked checkbox from class pcbox the checkbox from cc-box not work / not checked.

Where is the problem?

Comment: just a idea using `class` we can check same class item once

Comment: @Hamelraj any solution for this problem?

Comment: i have posted answer below just to get idea check \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check I have changed child chekboxes class as per parent check box value.

then when you click parent checkbox you can get value. i have used VueJs onclick event you can use what ever you prefer.

```
<ul id="treeview">
    @foreach ($parent_menus as $parent_menu)
        <li>
            {{ $parent_menu->Description }}
            <input type="checkbox" class="pc-box" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $parent_menu->ModuleID }}" @change="check($event)">
            <ul class="example">
                @foreach ($child_menus1 as $child_menu1)
                    @if ($parent_menu->ModuleID == $child_menu1->HeaderId)
                        <li data-expanded="true">
                            {{ $child_menu1->Description }}
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cc-box-{{$parent_menu->ModuleID}}" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu1->ModuleID }}">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($child_menus2 as $child_menu2)
                                    @if ($child_menu1->ModuleID == $child_menu2->HeaderId)
                                        <li>
                                            {{ $child_menu2->Description }}
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="cc-box-{{$parent_menu->ModuleID}}" name="menus_id[]" value="{{ $child_menu2->ModuleID }}">
                                        </li>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

VueJs method - but you can use javascript function

```
check(e){
   console.log(e.target.value);
   $(".cc-box-"+e.target.value).attr("checked", "true");
}
```